# How to get multiclass Keras model to output category name instead of probabilities?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I understand the idea of passing labels in training data to a Keras model as a one-hot encoding, but I'm trying to create a model that will return a string during inference, and not a one-hot encoding that I'd have to decode myself.

Specifically, I DON'T want to have to do the following:

```
encoder = LabelEncoder() 
encoder = encoder.fit(labels)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(labels)
y_true = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y). # Model accepts this during training

prediction = model.predict(query)
label_string = encoder.inverse_transform(prediction)
```

How can I create a model that will call `.predict()` and return something customized, such as the string of the highest prediction and its corresponding probability?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a complete model, and create a custom model on top of it that includes a post-processing function.

Let's take a pre-trained model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.data import chelsea

model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2()
```

That model comes with a function that takes the output probability matrix, and turns it into strings (you'll have to make your own)

```
decoder = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.decode_predictions
```

Then, we create a model that has two parts: 1) the model 2) the post-processing function

```
class NewModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, model, decoder):
        super(NewModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.decoder = decoder

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.model(x).numpy()
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x


m = NewModel(model, decoder)
```

Now, just call it with appropriate input:

```
cat_picture = tf.image.resize(chelsea(), (224, 224))[None, ...]/255

m(cat_picture)
```

```
[[('n02124075', 'Egyptian_cat', 0.7610773),
  ('n02123045', 'tabby', 0.12039327),
  ('n02123159', 'tiger_cat', 0.039847013),
  ('n02127052', 'lynx', 0.009957394),
  ('n04553703', 'washbasin', 0.0015057808)]]
```

It returns the output of the post-processing function.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My issue here is that the decoder needs to be provided separately... What if I want to save the model to disk and load it in another location, would I need to save the decoder as a pickle file and move it also?

Ideally I'd create a model that bakes in the label encode/decode step impicitly, allowing me to call model.fit(train_x, train_y, ...) where train_y is a list of strings

Comment: Well that would've been an important element to include in the question, since the main challenges of your issue don't really appear in your post. I honestly don't know. I think when you save a Tensorflow model, you can save custom objects along with it.